# ColorBox iframe rel (group)

Tags: jquery, iframe, colorbox, rel

im really stuck.. been sitting with this code forever now.. trying to make a gallery with ColorBox, seems very nice.. i just have one problem.. I just cant get it to be a group when using iframes...

http://www.lani.dk/thomas/temp/iframe_problem.zip

site

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>-</title>

 <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" />
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
function showColorBox(imageURL) {
$.fn.colorbox({ opacity: .6, open: true, href: imageURL });
}
</script>

 </head>
<body>
<iframe src="iframe.asp" name="iframename" width="400" height="400" frameborder='0'     id="iframename">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>-</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #999;
}
</style>

<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('a.colorbox').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    parent.showColorBox($(this).attr("href"));
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<p><a href="images/gallery/pic1.jpg" class="colorbox" rel="group1">pic1</a></p>
<p><a href="images/gallery/pic2.jpg" class="colorbox" rel="group1">pic2</a></p>
<p><a href="images/gallery/pic3.jpg" class="colorbox" rel="group1">pic2</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you try with the Pretty photo plugin. It is similar to what you need

Comment: May i ask what the purpose of the iframe is..? If you didn't use one you could just do `$('a.gallery').colorbox({rel:'group1'});`

Comment: its for a site where i already have iframe, the full background image is a slow moving slideshow - so i wonna open the gallery images on top of all - 

http://www.lani.dk/thomas/temp/snapshot.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Remember that ColorBox scans the DOM for assets to render at page load time. I'm suspecting that the plugin doesn't see the assets in the iframe and, as a result, doesn't recognize them.

PS. Love the candy-cane lips.